# Removing digital Signature tags from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, digital-signature

i need to know how the digital signature tags can be removed. its a enveloped digital signature

my xml file looks like the following

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <questionset>
    <question category="graph" /> 
 <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
    </SignedInfo>
 </Signature>
 </questionset>
```

i tried somethings

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
 xmlDoc.Load(new XmlTextReader(Doc));
 XmlNode rnode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("questionset/Signature");
 XmlNode parent = rnode.ParentNode;
 parent.RemoveChild(rnode);
 string newXML = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
 XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filename2, new UTF8Encoding(false));
 xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
 xmlWriter.Close();
```

but rnode returned null value..

and i tried using Linq

```
 XElement document = XElement.Load(Doc);
 XElement signElement = document.Descendants("Signature").FirstOrDefault<XElement>();
 signElement.Remove();
```

here also signElement returned null value.. so both didnt work.can someone tell me where i went wrong or can you tell me the right approach to remove the digital signature.

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement document = XElement.Load(Doc);

IEnumerable<XElement> signElements = document.Descendants("questionSet").Elements("Signature");
```

will get you the elements you wish to remove. In this case, `"Signature"`.

then call `Remove()`

```
document.Descendants("questionSet").Elements("Signature").Remove();
```

then save the xml back to a file if required;

```
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

See [MSDN Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.remove.aspx) for more detail.

Further, your LINQ to XML query

```
XElement signElement = document.Descendants("Signature").FirstOrDefault<XElement>();
```

would have gotten the descendants/children of "Signature" and then returned the first item in the collection. So you would have gotten the first "SignedInfo" node.

Comment: Post a valid xml and we'll test it.

Comment: Post your expected output.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <questionset>
    <question category="graph" /> 
  </questionset>